# Qt + gif + alpha

Tags: qt, gif, alpha

How to make a transparent background in QLabel with QMovie? Gif already has set transparency. 
I need to do something like KamikadzeCat or Felix. It's cats, that do something on Homescreen. I tried to write:

```
QLabel lb;
QMovie mv1("ooo.gif");
lb.setMovie(&mv1);
mv1.start();
lb.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
lb.show();
```

Also I tryed to write:

```
lb.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(225,255,255,0);");
```

Bur it's not working at all. 
if first time the label was with gray background, and in the second time I tried to write a lot of numbers in rgba, but it was useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute to your QLabel to get a translucent background:

```
yourLabel->setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I tried to solve this problem about 2 days and thought than I couldn't do this, but you saved me!